# Tensorflow AttributeError: 'TFShouldUseWarningWrapper' object has no attribute 'pack'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get the Error Message in the third line.

> AttributeError: 'TFShouldUseWarningWrapper' object has no attribute
>   'pack'

But it is a TensorArray....

```
flat_container=tf.TensorArray(tf.float32,self.batch_size*self.memory_size)    
flat_allocation=flat_container.scatter(flat_mapped_usage_sorted_index,flat_allocation_unsorted)
flat_allocation_packed=flat_allocation.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow 1.0 the `pack()` function was renamed to `tf.stack()`.

Try your code with the new command and should work.